# Why is this JSON file reading strangly

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON document here. I have validated it with [JSlint](http://jsonlint.com/).

The JSON is of this format:

```
[{
    "date": "2017-02-10",
    " action": "Do a thing",
    "state": "closed",
    "url": "https:someurl.com"
}, 
....
```

I have some HTML [here](http://joereddington.com/Vision/web/index.html), which exists only to read and output the JSON.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        deadlines = []
        start();

        function start() {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", "http://joereddington.com/deadlines.json");
            req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
            req.send(null);
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                    deadlines = obj
                    for (deadline in deadlines) {
                        var output = '';
                        for (var property in deadline) {
                            console.log(property)
                            output += property + ': ' + deadline[property] + '; ';
                        }
                        console.log(output);
                        console.log(deadline.date)
                        console.log(deadline.action)
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

However, when I try and list the properties of each object, I get very strange results:

[image]

rather than the names and values I'm looking for. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `deadlines` is an **array**. So it must be iterated by `for`, not `for..in`

Comment: You don't have a cross-origin header on your JSON so I can't properly diagnose it. Also, use `deadlines.forEach(function (deadline) { ... })` instead of `for (x in y)` for looping over arrays.

Comment: @Liam Gray The request is same-domain so CORS is not applied here.

Comment: `var property in deadline` should be `var property of deadline`

Comment: @hindmost - that's the one! Do you want to make that an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(JSON.parse(deadlines), function (index, deadline) {
    var output = '';
    for (var property in deadline) {
        console.log(property)
        output += property + ': ' + deadline[property] + '; ';
    }
    console.log(output);
    console.log(deadline.date);
    console.log(deadline.action);
});
```

Your JSON string contains extra space.  It should be "action" not " action".

Comment: The extra space was a good call.  That and one other bit solved this.

Answer (score 0):

[**`for...in`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops over the keys (since it's an array: `"0"`, `"1"` ...). Use [**`for...of`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or [**`forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a basic [**`for`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop.

I recommend `forEach` like this:

```
deadlines.forEach(function(deadline) {
    // ...   
});
```